# D3 map not distinguishing click from select text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a interactive map with D3/SVG. However, when I click on it with a mobile phone, the browser understands as "select text", showing me the option the button to "SELECT ALL".

Is there any native way to D3 distinguish it or should I look for solutions to disable "select text" anywhere in my site?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure css for this. This will also disable text selection on desktop browsers as well.
Webkit's touch callout is not a standard feature so it might not work for all users.

```
svg text {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-touch-callout